# Change list comprehension to show results in print statement without square brackets and quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, list-comprehension

I'm trying to do a simple math which is supposed to be pretty straightforward and easy.

```
I24 = '4.64%'
J24 = 96.8
K24 = 96.8
```

I'm using two list comprehensions in my print statement, not sure if I should even use a list comprehension for something like this

```
['control' if i < 50 else 'variant' for i in [J24]] ## if J24 is less than 50 then 'control' else 'variant'.. as you see I'm taking J24 into a list

# if K24 < 75 then 'No evidence of difference' if K24 >= 85 then 'Meaningful difference', if K24 between 75 & 84 then 'Marginal difference'

['No evidence of difference' if x < 75 else 'Meaningful difference' if x >= 85 else 'Marginal difference' for x in [K24]]
```

When I print the statement--

```
print("V to Qc uplift "+I24+' ('+str(K24)+'%'+' probability of '+ str(['control' if i < 50 else 'variant' for i in [J24]]) + ' being better). '+str(['No evidence of difference' if x < 75 else 'Meaningful difference' if x >= 85 else 'Marginal difference' for x in [K24]]))
```

My output looks like this

```
V to Qc uplift 4.64% (96.8% probability of ['variant'] being better). ['Meaningful difference']
```

I want my output to look without the square brackets and quotes

Like this:

```
V to Qc uplift 4.64% (96.8% probability of variant being better). Meaningful difference
```

I've used list comprehension, but Im not sure if that's the best solution. Thank you so much for your help ! :)

Comment: "not sure if I should even use a list comprehension for something like this" - no, you shouldn't. Why manipulate lists of 1 item? Furthermore, this is where the brackets you don't want come from...

Comment: Thank you @ThierryLathuille
Learnt something today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
print("V to Qc uplift "+I24+' ('+str(K24)+'%'+' probability of '+ str('control' if J24 < 50 else 'variant') + ' being better). '+str('No evidence of difference' if K24 < 75 else 'Meaningful difference' if K24 >= 85 else 'Marginal difference'))
```

Don't do a for loop, instead just do a if statement.

Comment: Awesome ! That's exactly what I wanted. I guess you forgot to update ['control' if J24 < 50 else 'variant'] to ('control' if J24 < 50 else 'variant')

It works for the 'Marginal difference' part though since you've updated that. 

Thank you for your help :) :)

Comment: It wasn't a for loop, it isn't an if statement, and the `str` is still pointless.